# Webpack: Each script in its own file

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to make webpack to emit files not in one single file but in separate files with saving names and hierarchy? The problem is that I have a large output script that chrome dev tools even can't pretty it. I can't use source maps because they don't work (i.e. breakpoint points to empty space).

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The problem is that it is imposible to debug application using webpack. I am looking for any posiible solutions

Comment: It's not a proper problem explanation: provide more details, since "it is imposible to debug application using webpack" is not descriptive - I can debug apps bundled with webpack without any problems as well as thousands of other developers.

Comment: webpack makes one single file, it is not easy to debug one single file, and webpack creates source maps which should cover this problem, but they don't work correctly, for example I set "break on exceptions", but it stops on empty line using source maps